# Python return with multiple dictionaries from a function

Tags: python, dictionary, return

my problem is that I have two function and one of it's return value is two dictionaries in the following way:

```
def fnct1():
    return dict1, dict2
```

so it's returning into my other function which return value is the two dictionaries from the previous function and also a new dictionary, so something like this

```
 def fnct2():
     return dict3, fnct(1)
```

the problem with this is that is has the following result:

```
({dict3},({dict1},{dict2})
```

but I want it to look the following way:

```
({dict3},{dict1},{dict2})
```

Comment: could you show the code you've come up with? also, [the help centre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) has some info on the correct formatting for code.

Comment: Sorry for the bad formatting I will be more careful in the future

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since your function returns a tuple, you need to either return the individual tuple items, or unpack them:

```
def fnct1():
    dict1 = { "name": "d1" }
    dict2 = { "name": "d2" }
    return dict1, dict2

def fnct2():
    dict3 = { "name": "d3" }
    res = fnct1() 
    return dict3, res[0], res[1] # return the individual tuple elements

# alternative implementation of fnct2:
def fnct2():
    dict3 = { "name": "d3" }
    d1, d2 = fnct1() # unpack your tuple
    return dict3, d1, d2

print(fnct2())
# Output: ({'name': 'd3'}, {'name': 'd1'}, {'name': 'd2'})
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer that was what I was looking for, or is there any way to add dict3 into the tuple instead of unpacking the two what are already there?

Comment: @Klftau Tuples are immutable so you cannot change them, however you can add tuples together (in a new tuple) to imitate this behavior. Try `return (dict3,) + fnct1()`.

Answer (score 5):

You could unpack the values from `fnct1()` before returning them:

```
def fnct2():
    dict1, dict2 = fnct1()
    return dict3, dict1, dict2
```

Answer (score 2):

If you say the returned value of the 1st function is `a`. In the 2nd just `return a[0], a[1], otherDict`.